# Setting up WebLogic server for developing

Tags: weblogic, eclipse

Guys I'm in the middle of a youtube series teaching me about web services 
using Eclipse/Java

Now I'm kinda stuck at a point and maybe you could help me out.
It involves setting up a server and I have no experience with that

In this following youtube link, he creates a 'New Dynamic Web Project'
Then using adapter/toolkit installed into eclipse he picks 'Oracle WebLogic Server'

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=gtmAwuH3hqA#t=50

So as the video shows, this requires you to have a server installed on the computer

**What I did:** I went to Oracle, downloaded the WebLogic 12.1.2 developing free server, 185mb zip file. I extracted those files to a folder,
Then picked the right version under 'Pick New Runtime Server' in Eclipse
Then as done 01:36 in the video, I pointed to that new folder as 'WebLogic Home'

Eclipse error: **The path "C:\weblogic" does not contain a valid WebLogic Server install.**

I've been browsing through that folder, and googled a Little to see how I need to install this server, and I can't really find anything about not, not on Oracles site aswell.
At least not something I understand

So hope you can help me
/Allan

Comment: Okay, so I found a Readme
And set the MW_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables
now unpacking, will remove this post when I'm done, ready and problem free